# PRAM (Pararell Random Access Machine) simulator

Tags: parallel-processing

Are there any [PRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Random_Access_Machine) simulators?

I want to test some simple pararell algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a language/compiler called Fork that claims to have a simulator in the distro called *pramsim* that's been recently ported to linux.
http://www.ida.liu.se/~chrke/fork95.html

Disclaimer: I've no hands-on experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [PRAM Machine Simulator](http://sourceforge.net/p/prammachine/home/Home/) by Adam Stański (the source code is also available).

Answer (score 0):

PRAM is not a very realistic model, ignoring the two factors that make parallel computation so difficult: synchronization and communication.  You might have more results looking at Bulk Synchronous Processing (BSP) for example. If you are looking for a practical library, you could look into a Fork/Join style library such as IntelTBB or Java util.concurrency.

edit: To actually answer the question: Sorry, I do not know of any PRAM simulator. I have only seen it used in modified form for complexity-analysis.

Comment: I know it is not realistic, that's why I am looking for a simulator. I want to test some algorithms but I dont care about the performance.